# How can I get my menu control to center?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ASP.Net's Menu control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx, which I'm trying to position.

Markup for the menu is this

```
<asp:Menu ID="SiteMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" BorderColor="Blue" Font-Size="XX-Large" StaticMenuItemStyle-BackColor = "Pink" StaticMenuItemStyle-HorizontalPadding = "11">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Articles" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Wiki" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Forums" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Links" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

So I just figured I'd add  tags around it,

```
<div horizontal-align:center>
<asp:Menu ID="SiteMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" BorderColor="Blue" Font-Size="XX-Large" StaticMenuItemStyle-BackColor = "Pink" StaticMenuItemStyle-HorizontalPadding = "11">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Articles" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Wiki" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Forums" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Links" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
</div>
```

but nah that didn't work. So what's my next move?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

oops , you should use margins and widths :

```
<div style="margin:0 auto 0 auto; width:750px;">
<asp:Menu ID="SiteMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" BorderColor="Blue" Font-Size="XX-Large" StaticMenuItemStyle-BackColor = "Pink" StaticMenuItemStyle-HorizontalPadding = "11">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Articles" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Wiki" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Forums" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Links" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
</div>
```

Comment: also set width to 750 for the <asp:Menu>

Answer (score 1):

Use margin like:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

This help you make it automatically centered to its parent element.